# SVG doesn't render fonts in Firefox (works in IE9 and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, vector, svg

I've got vector logo in PSD file. When I export it as AI (Adobe Illustrator) file and then convert to SVG I get something like this:

```
<tspan
             x="0 34.799999 68.75"
             y="0"
             id="tspan22"
             style="font-size:50px;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;font-family:Novecento wide Book;-inkscape-font-specification:Novecentowide-Bold">AI</tspan>
```

This is only a short part of full SVG file but you can see that it creates letters and attempts to use fonts. Which fails...

[image]

I rather want it to export SVG file as stand-alone vector that doesn't require any fonts. How can this be done?

Comment: Mozilla [decided not to support SVG fonts in Firefox because they felt it could hurt adoption of the more-recent Web Open Font Format (WOFF)](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2010/06/not-implementing-features-is-hard_03.html).

Comment: While this may be true, it's not terribly relevant given that the OP is not using SVG fonts.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to make it VECTOR SVG rather than the one that requires custom font?

Comment: Is there anything in the Firefox Error Console?

Comment: @RobertLongson No, but I'm sure that it just doesn't support font-face for SVG. I already found a way to convert it into vector in Illustrator and save correctly. File size remains alright and it works just like it should when scaled.

Comment: @RobertLongson Pardon, I misread "`@font-face` in SVG file" as "`@font-face` with SVG file".

Comment: I'm sure Firefox does support @font-face. Here's a working example: https://jwatt.org/svg-open/2009/demos/font-face/web-fonts-in-html-and-svg.xhtml

Comment: have the same problem, fyi its also work well in opera.

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities:

1. Try putting single-quotes around the font-family name, under the assumption that Firefox is not recognizing the whole string, as so:

   `font-family:'Novecento wide Book';`
2. Try converting the Text within AI or PSD to a Vector / Shape before exporting as SVG. That will remove the reliance on any font-family, which is a consideration especially if you intend to publish this on the Web. Should work perfectly that way.

Comment: Yet another option is to embed the font inside of the SVG document, see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5167/81543

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the text in a vector program like illustrator and select outline text. This will keep your font no matter which browser.

Comment: This is going to increase considerably the file weight (unless you only have a handful of characters).

Answer (score 1):

I have used embedded fonts this way in IE11, Chrome and Firefox with no issues:

```
<svg...>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 52.1787 206.4395)" fill="#F7F7F7" font-family="'Roboto'" font-weight="400" font-size="16">Lorem Ipsum</text>
</svg>
```

Note the font-family attribute is doublequoted. Thats the way illustrator does it. Take note to use the proper fontface name. Illustrator for examples likes to put "'Roboto-Regular'" which could be not the proper name of the font-face