# SVG fonts in Firefox other than serif and sans-serif?

Tags: firefox, svg, fonts, vector-graphics

I am using fonts in an embedded SVG file rendered in Firefox (v26, "Nightly" and future versions). Other than the two fonts `serif` and `sans-serif`, what else is available?

My SVG is generated in Adobe Illustrator. [Any font-family names I specify only render correctly in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866139/svg-doesnt-render-fonts-in-firefox-works-in-ie9-and-chrome) and I cannot use outlines as a workaround, as I will be annotating the SVG with dynamically-generated label text.

Other than using outlines, what is the process for annotating SVG documents with custom `text` elements, such that they will render correctly in Firefox?

Comment: Is this question about using fonts which are *defined with SVG*, or importing a particular font to use within SVG? I'm confused because the bounty message seems directed towards the former case, but there's no specific mention of *SVG fonts* in the question.

Answer (score 4):

### On making your SVG render pretty fonts

It is *entirely possible* for Firefox to present SVG `text` in a custom font. For example, it can be done as follows:

```
 <svg>
   <style>
     @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
     text { font-family:Varela Round, sans-serif; }
   </style>
   <text y="20">I will appear in a custom font</text>
 </svg>
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34x36/) demonstrates the usage to some extent. Note that in jsfiddle the CSS is included as an HTML style sheet, not directly in the CSS.

The following can be used as a data URL, i.e. you may copy an paste it directly into the address bar. It demonstrates using `@import` from the SVG directly.)

```
data:text/html, <svg><style>@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);text { font-family:Varela Round, sans-serif; }</style><text y="20">I will appear in a custom font</text></svg>)
```

(Of the current popular browsers, only Firefox supports data URLs in the address bar. Also if you change the data's MIME to `image/svg+xml` it won't work in Firefox.

In a comment on the previous answer to this question, Robert Longson also shared a link [demonstrating an imported font](https://jwatt.org/svg-open/2009/demos/font-face/web-fonts-in-html-and-svg.xhtml) using `<link rel=stylesheet`. Note that some of the fonts on that page are rejected by Firefox for technical reasons which I don't understand. However, almost all of them work.

---

### Regarding the politics around *SVG Fonts*

*SVG Fonts* is a [branch of the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html) which deals with *defining your font in an SVG file*. This is totally different to *using a font in an SVG file*, which I have outlined above.

[Mozilla's position on the SVG Font spec](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SVGFonts), as I understand it, is that the only benefit to SVG fonts is that you can define your font by hand in a text editor. [Others have expressed similar opinions.](http://jeremie.patonnier.net/post/2011/02/07/Why-are-SVG-Fonts-so-different) This is why Mozilla have concentrated on WOFF.

---

The current state of [importing](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20font) [web](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) [fonts](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot) is such that, to achieve cross-browser/device compatibility, you have to provide multiple different font formats. This is unfortunate, but hardly the end of the world in my opinion.

Comment: I don't have the rights to redistribute the "pretty" font in question, so while I appreciate you taking the time to write this up, I cannot use your answer to work around what appears to be a weird bug with Firefox that Mozilla developers are apparently deliberately choosing to ignore.

Comment: @Jeremy Regardless of this answer not being helpful in the OP case, I found it to be very helpful in my own usecase.

Comment: @AlexReynolds If you aren't allowed to distribute the font, you could vectorize the text before saving as SVG.

Comment: As I noted in the question, I cannot use outlines because I will be rendering dynamically-generated text in the SVG.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, Mozilla has indefinitely postponed SVG font implementation to focus on WOFF. In fact this bug was even labeled on Bugzilla as "RESOVLVEDWONTFIX". Here is the link for [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_fonts) and the link on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119490).

Admittedly I do not know enough about SVG Font to know if the `CSS @font-face` element will work and I also saw reference to Openfont.

Comment: I feel weird about having to put Internet Explorer and Firefox into the same category of yesterday's non-standards compliant browsers. But that's Mozilla's choice, I guess.

Comment: One difference between FF and IE is that [Mozilla provide an explanation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SVGFonts). I can confirm that `@font-face` works in Firefox, too, so flaming Mozilla seems rather unnecessary and a bit rude.

Comment: The following Mozilla document suggests that `@font-face` does not work with SVG and Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: Sure it does: try this link https://jwatt.org/svg-open/2009/demos/font-face/web-fonts-in-html-and-svg.xhtml

Comment: Believe me I did not want to post a response burning Firefox as it is my favorite browser. I just could not believe what I read. I am glad to here that there is a solution through CSS though.