# Why is Firefox rendering my SVG so badly?

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, svg

I just received an SVG file which I want to include into my HTML code.
Everything is working properly, except that Firefox somehow just renders the font int the SVG extremely bad.

Here's two screenshots:

[image: Opera/Chrome -> perfectly fine]
Opera/Chrome -> perfectly fine

[image: Firefox -> awful]
Firefox -> awful

I searched for about two hours now and didn't find any useful hints at all.
What could the reason be?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Here's the XML Code from the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="98px" height="139px" viewBox="0 0 98 139" enable-background="new 0 0 98 139" xml:space="preserve">
<image overflow="visible" width="98" height="139" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA....." transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)">
</image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please include the SVG code you've used *in* the question, rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: @TylerH I added the code, though I don't think it has anything to do with it, since scaling etc. works fine

Comment: We need the real jpeg data otherwise we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Might want to consider the options detailed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866139/svg-doesnt-render-fonts-in-firefox-works-in-ie9-and-chrome as well.

Comment: @RichardJapenga I don't think that will help if the text is actually from a raster image.

Comment: @RobertLongson you are right, got caught in the default approach of handling SVG, it looks like MDN actually states that with Illustrator export there might be some post-processing necessary. Also older versions of Firefox seemed to have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954028/firefox-svg-graphics-blurry

So maybe the dimensions are changed and Firefox is not able to properly render it. But we need the real jpeg to test that out.